# Unable to configure Dependency Injection - IoC in WINUI3 app - visual studio 2022

Tags: mvvm, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, visual-studio-2022, winui-3

someone has the same problem using this code in the new WINUI3 app (Visual Studio 2022) as explained https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/ioc :

```cs
        public sealed partial class App : Application
        {
    

        public App()
        {
            Services = ConfigureServices();
    
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the current <see cref="App"/> instance in use
        /// </summary>
        public new static App Current => (App)Application.Current;
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the <see cref="IServiceProvider"/> instance to resolve application services.
        /// </summary>
        public IServiceProvider Services { get; }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Configures the services for the application.
        /// </summary>
        private static IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
    
            services.AddSingleton<IFilesService, FilesService>();
            services.AddSingleton<ISettingsService, SettingsService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IClipboardService, ClipboardService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IShareService, ShareService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IEmailService, EmailService>();
    
            return services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
    }
```

This is NUGET packages installed

[image]

and this is my error:

[image]

Comment: Prefer not posting exception information, compiler messages and code as images, as explained why [here](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/). Post instead the full compiler error message.

Comment: ps. you're likely missing a namespace declaration at the top of your file.

Comment: @Steven, As Andrew ansewer below, I don't had installed Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection Nuget Packages, using directive was already declarate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install:

**Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection**

instead of,

**Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions**

Comment: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection